# How to use coordinates from a sql table as parameter input in Weather URL API SSIS script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, api, ssis

I have created a SSIS-project that retrieves weather information (JSON format) using a Web API in a script task. I've been following this tutorial :[Weather data API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6t2mB1kH6ZI) which works great if you only want to retrieve weather information from a fixed set of coordinates.
My goal now is to use a table where I have stored some coordinates as variable input in the API URL parameters instead of having the coordinates already set in the URL https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact.json?lat=55.596&lon=15

So what I have done so for

1. Created a Script task that gathers the weather information:

```html
#region Help:  Introduction to the script task
/* The Script Task allows you to perform virtually any operation that can be accomplished in
 * a .Net application within the context of an Integration Services control flow. 
 * 
 * Expand the other regions which have "Help" prefixes for examples of specific ways to use
 * Integration Services features within this script task. */
#endregion


#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
#endregion

namespace ST_6f60bececd8f4f94afaf758869590918
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {
            string Longitude =  (string)Dts.Variables["User::Longitude"].Value.ToString();
            string Latitude =  (string)Dts.Variables["User::Latitude"].Value.ToString();
            var url = @"https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact.json?lat=55.596&lon=15";
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            req.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            var syncClient = new WebClient();
            syncClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "acmeweathersite.com support@acmeweathersite.com");
            var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

            string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Weather;Integrated Security=True;";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand Storproc =
                  new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Weather] (JSONData)
                                    select @JSONData", conn);
                Storproc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JSONData", content.ToString());
                conn.Open();
                Storproc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

            }
            // TODO: Add your code here

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

2. Created a SQL table with coordinates:

```html
create table Coordinates(
             Municipality nvarchar(50),
             Latitide nvarchar(50),
             Longitude nvarchar(50)
             )
INSERT INTO Coordinates (Municipality, Latitide, Longitude)
VALUES (114, 59.5166667, 17.9),
        (115, 59.5833333, 18.2),
        (117, 59.5, 18.45)
```

3. Added the coordinates table as an SQL task:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Finally I added the two variables in the Script task code:

```html
 string Longitude =  (string)Dts.Variables["User::Longitude"].Value.ToString();
string Latitude =  (string)Dts.Variables["User::Latitude"].Value.ToString();
var url = @"https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact.json?lat=Latitude&lon=Longitude";
```

But when I execute the package the Foreach Loop Container just loops forever, no errors pops up but no data is being stored in the database table either. It feels like I have missed something but no really sure what. Very novice when it comes to variables in SSIS so excuse my lack of knowledge. in my example I am using a SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are nearly there.

Few things to check:

In your SQL, you are selecting 3 columns, so, the 'index' for these columns would be:

```
Municipality -> index = 0
Latitide -> index = 1
Longitude -> index = 2
```

i.e., in the variable mapping, you need to use index 1 and 2 instead of zero for all.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/foreach-loop-container?view=sql-server-ver15

> The first column defined in the enumerator item has the index value 0, the second column 1, and so on.

Your spelling for the columns also seems different (Latitide Vs Latitude). Cross-check this as well. i.e., if you run your sql statement manually are you able to see the data ? What are the column names for the result ?

You can also check the variables in your script task (for debugging purposes) by adding a `MessageBox`.
E.g.,

```
string longitude = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Longitude"].Value.ToString();
string latitide = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Latitide"].Value.ToString();
string municipality = (string)Dts.Variables["User::Municipality"].Value.ToString();

MessageBox.Show("longitude:" + longitude + ", latitide:" + latitide + ", municipality: " + municipality);
```

Comment: Thank you the Index setting solved the issue. :). The only problem is that the JSON data is being stored as 3 different rows (one for each coordinates) instead of one big array that holds everything. So when I parse the array data now stored in one of my tables called "Weather" which is in JSON format into another table called "WeatherByHour" in sql structured format it only seems to use the first row anyways.

Comment: I have the code example for the transforming of the JSON data into tabled structured data here: https://codeshare.io/21wBoz